# C++ Modifying class object within a vector

Tags: c++

My issue is my last increment_watch function. I would like to be able modify parts of the Movie class while it is in a vector container. Right now I am only able to grab a specific Movie object and its increment but I am unable to change or modify any of it while it is in a vector. I would like to be able to modify or add +1 to the watched element. Is this at all possible?

EDIT: I have updated the "increment_watched" function taking suggestions from the comments. I have tried to pass by reference the watched variable but the "mov.set_watched" call in the increment_watched function is not taking effect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Movie {
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Movie &p);
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string ratting;
    int watched;
public:
    Movie() = default;
    Movie(std::string name, std::string ratting, int watched) 
        : name{name}, ratting{ratting}, watched{watched}  {}

    void increment_watched(std::vector<Movie> vec, std::string name);

    bool operator<(const Movie &rhs) const {                       // always overload
        return this->watched < rhs.watched;
    }
    bool operator==(const Movie &rhs) const {
        return (this->name == rhs.name && this->watched == rhs.watched);    // always overload
    }

    void set_name(std::string name) {
        this->name = name; 
    }

    std::string getName() { 
        return name; 
    }

    void set_ratting(std::string ratting) {
        this->ratting = ratting; 
    }

    std::string getRatting() { 
        return ratting; 
    }

    void set_watched(int watched) {
        this->watched = watched; 
    }

    int getWatched() { 
        return watched; 
    }

};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Movie &p) {
    os << p.name << " : " << p.ratting << " : " << p.watched;
    return os;
}

// template function to display any vector
template <typename T>
void display(const std::vector<T> &lem) {
    std::cout << "[ ";
    for (const auto &elem: lem)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    std::cout <<  " ]"<< std::endl;
}

// I want to modify this function to increment the "watched" variable by one
void increment_watched(std::vector<Movie> vec, std::string name, int &watched){
    watched =+ 1;
    for (auto &mov: vec){
        if (mov.getName() == name){
            std::cout << name << std::endl;
            mov.set_watched(watched); 
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    std::vector<Movie> vec;
    int watched = 1;

    Movie p1 {"Star Wars", "PG", 2};
    Movie p2 {"Indiana Jones", "PG", 1};
    Movie p3 {"Matrix", "PG-13", 5};

    vec.push_back(p2);
    vec.push_back(p3);

    std::cout << p1.getName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << p1.getRatting() << std::endl;
    
    p1.set_watched(100);
    vec.push_back(p1);
    
    std::cout << p1.getWatched() << std::endl;
    display(vec);

     
    increment_watched(vec, "Star Wars", watched);
    display(vec);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"but I am unable to change or modify any of it while it is in a vector"_ Can you [edit] and elaborate about that please? Which error message are you getting? Does your code produce some unexpected output? You'll need to be precise about that to get help with your problems.

Comment: Do you know about braces in context of `if` conditions? `if (mov.getWatched() == watched)` doesn't guard `watched++;`

Comment: `increment_watched(std::vector<T> vec, std::string name, int watched)` - here `vec` is passed by value (i.e. copied), and thus changes within the function will *not* be reflected back to the caller's vector. Change the argument to `std::vector<T> &vec` . And the object type being stored has *nothing* to do with this. It doesn't have to be a "class" object. A vector of `int` would suffer the same problem.

Comment: How is this question different from your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67674216/c-how-to-modify-class-objects-in-a-vector) (now deleted) question?

Comment: I have a sense, that I saw this exact question, few hours ago. Which was closed as a duplicate, to the question explaining pass by reference vs pass by value. Which is, what it seems, that is going on here - `increment_watched` needs to accept the vector by reference, to be able to do modifications to it.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't repost the same question over and over again.

Comment: And besides the reference issue, you never even attempt to modify `mov.watched`. Perhaps you should call `mov.set_watched()` (once you've fixed the reference problem)? Or are you really trying to modify the argument `watched`? In which case you need to pass it too by reference.

Comment: 1. What is the code supposed to do? 2. What is it doing wrong? Please (a) answer these questions at the top of your post and (b) remove as much as possible of the code without making it impossible to build or see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Thank you user WhozCraig, this lead me to answering my question!
You response lead the to the correct output. I wanted to change the values and completely over looked passing the vec variable to pass by reference. I knew it was something small that I was over looking

To all those who posted helpful comments to help post better questions on the site, thank you. I am new to StackOverflow. I will review the provided helpful links in order to post better questions in the future. Some commented that I posted the same question twice, I panicked and deleted the post because it was locked, I didnt know what to do so I thought I would start over.

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Movie {
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Movie &p);
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string ratting;
    int watched;
public:
    Movie() = default;
    Movie(std::string name, std::string ratting, int watched) 
        : name{name}, ratting{ratting}, watched{watched}  {}

    void increment_watched(std::vector<Movie> vec, std::string name);

    bool operator<(const Movie &rhs) const {                       // always overload
        return this->watched < rhs.watched;
    }
    bool operator==(const Movie &rhs) const {
        return (this->name == rhs.name && this->watched == rhs.watched);    // always overload
    }

    void set_name(std::string name) {
        this->name = name; 
    }

    std::string getName() { 
        return name; 
    }

    void set_ratting(std::string ratting) {
        this->ratting = ratting; 
    }

    std::string getRatting() { 
        return ratting; 
    }

    void set_watched(int watched) {
        this->watched = watched; 
    }

    int getWatched() { 
        return watched; 
    }

};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Movie &p) {
    os << p.name << " : " << p.ratting << " : " << p.watched;
    return os;
}

// template function to display any vector
template <typename T>
void display(const std::vector<T> &lem) {
    std::cout << "[ ";
    for (const auto &elem: lem)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    std::cout <<  " ]"<< std::endl;
}

// I want to modify this function to increment the "watched" variable by one
void increment_watched(std::vector<Movie> &vec, std::string name, int &watched){
    for (auto &mov: vec){
        if (mov.getName() == name){
            std::cout << name << std::endl;
            mov.set_watched(watched + 1); 
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    std::vector<Movie> vec;
    int watched = 3;

    Movie p1 {"Star Wars", "PG", 2};
    Movie p2 {"Indiana Jones", "PG", 1};
    Movie p3 {"Matrix", "PG-13", 5};

    vec.push_back(p2);
    vec.push_back(p3);

    std::cout << p1.getName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << p1.getRatting() << std::endl;
    
    p1.set_watched(100);
    vec.push_back(p1);
    
    std::cout << p1.getWatched() << std::endl;
    display(vec);

     
    increment_watched(vec, "Star Wars", watched);
    display(vec);

    return 0;
}
```